# How do I update data in an array

Tags: powershell

I have output from a SQL query in $data. It has three columns, ID, Name, NewIssue.
The New Issue is either True or False, I would like the array to have Yes and No instead.
But I do not understand how the line below is executed correctly,

```
"$data.NewIssue -eq 'FALSE'"
```

but when I try

```
$data.NewIssue = 'No'
```

I get this error...

"String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.Couldn't store  in NewIssue Column.  Expected type is Boolean."

```
$data | foreach {
    if ($data.NewIssue -eq 'FALSE') {
        $data.NewIssue = 'No'
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the NewIssue property is not a `[String]` so it can't store any old text you want it to. It is specifically `[Boolean]` which means it is True or it is False and there is no ifs, ands, or buts about it. If you want it to say Yes or No, or Yep or Nah, or any other thing you would need to add a new member to each object in the array of objects as a string, and set that string to Yes if NewIssue is True, or No if NewIssue is False. There is no easy way to remove the existing NewIssue member that I know of, or to re-type it as a string.

If you really, really wanted to you could loop through the array, and add each item to a new array as new objects including the original ID, and Name, and create NewIssue as a string where if it is True you set it as Yes, and if it is False you set it as No.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you should never, ever, ever compare booleans to strings. Mainly because:

```
$true -eq 'False'
```

PowerShell is showing you 'False' for your boolean column, because people read strings. That does not mean that string 'False' is equal to value of your property.

On the replacing column value: you can always use `Select-Object` for that:

```
$Data = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        NewIssue = $true
        Title = 'Foo'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        NewIssue = $false
        Title = 'Bar'
    }
)

$Data | Select-Object -Property *, @{
    Name = 'NewIssue'
    Expression = {
        if ($_.NewIssue) {
            'Yes'
        } else {
            'No'
        }
    }
} -ExcludeProperty NewIssue
```